# Opening RDLC Report in ReportViewer in C# cause <datatype>.Parse() methods to thrown 'Input string was not in a correct format' Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc, string-parsing

I am writing an accountant software containing windows forms. I have a lot of forms and a lot of code so it is absolutely useless to share a snippet of it because it cannot show anything of the program logic.

My problem here is that I have created an RDLC report for printing invoices and I have put it in a ReportViewer control. It works fine. But after I open the form containing the ReportViewer and go back to other forms the Parsing methods start failing no matter the value.

For example:

```
decimal.Parse("0.00");
```

will cause 'Input string was not in a correct format' Exception.
This problem doesn't occur unless I open the Report.
Please help!
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate your floating part with , instead of .

```
decimal.Parse("0,00");
```

Will work

Comment: Omg... I changed the Culture to Bulgarian in the Report and that's why it does not parse properly... Thank you for helping me find my stupid mistake.